# Find ring homorphisms from $\Bbb Z_2$ to $\Bbb Z_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to find all ring homomorphisms $\phi: \Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z_6$.

I know this is an easy problem , but I am having trouble grasping it so I cannot find what the answer is. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Does your definition of ring homomorphism require that $1$ be sent to $1$?

Comment: BTW, there is no need to repeat the tags in the title.

Comment: Well yes and I know 2|6, but the problem I am having is I do not know how to express ring homomorphisms. You can show me another example, but I really want to know how to express them.

Answer (score 1):

$Z_2$ is a field, so it has no nontrivial proper ideals. Therefore either $\ker \phi=Z_2$ or $\ker \phi = 0$. The first case corresponds to the zero homomorphism. In the second case, $\phi$ is injective. But $Z_6$ has only one ideal isomorphic to $Z_2$, namely $\{0, 3\}$. Since $0$ must map to $0$ we see this map is uniquely determined. Therefore there are only two ring homomorphisms from $Z_2$ to $Z_6$.

Edit: It is easy to show that any ring homomorphism  $\phi:Z_n \to Z_m$ is determined completely by the value of $\phi(1)$. Clearly if we artificially restrict $\phi(1)=1$ then there could only ever be one such homomorphism and our whole theory of homomorphisms between the $Z_m$'s will be sterile. The very fact that this question is posed indicates that we are working with the more usual definition in the study of these rings, where a homomorphism need not map 1 to 1.

Comment: Unless 1 must go to 1; in that case there is only 1.

Comment: 1 need not map to 1

Comment: It depends on your definition of ring homomorphism.

Comment: Correct; in mine, 1 need not map to 1